# Flutter mobx observer not working on List.firstWhere

Tags: flutter, dart, mobx

Hi I want to update my model list.

My model;

```
class Question {
    String id;
    String title;
    String questionInfo;
    String questionInfoSub;
    List<Answers> answers;
}
```

My view;

```
 ListView buildListView(ServiceStore _serviceStore, context) {
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _serviceStore.answersSummaryList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Observer(builder: (context) {
                return ReadOnlyWidget(
                  question: _serviceStore.answersSummaryList[index],
                  editIcon: true,
                  onPress: () {
                    showModalBottomSheetSummary(
                        context, _serviceStore.answersSummaryList[index]);
                  },
                );
              });
            });
      }
```

I am updating my object in showModalBottomSheetSummary with action function;

'''

```
 @observable
  ObservableList<Question> _answersSummaryList = new ObservableList();

@action
  updateAnswer(Question question) {
 

  
//I am making false my previously chosen answer
    _answersSummaryList
        .firstWhere((item) => item.id == question.id)
        .answers
        .firstWhere((element) => element.isSelected == true)
        .isSelected = false;

//I m making true what i want answer

    _answersSummaryList
        .firstWhere((item) => item.id == question.id)
        .answers
        .firstWhere((element) => element.id == _answerId)
        .isSelected = true;


//Checking if it has changed here.it is changing

        _answersSummaryList.forEach((element) {.   
          element.answers.forEach((element) {
            print(element.title);
            print(element.isSelected);
          });
    
      }
```

If I use .remove function for list. it is running and removing on screen with observer but when I change my answer with first Where . it is not changing on screen but changing at back.

Comment: you have a list of Answers inside List of Question. One way I've solved this is creating another store for Answer which extends the Answer model. And I can use the Answer store(not model), and it seems to react.

Answer (score 0):

As we know mobX doesn't work with regular List, we have ObservableList.

And your Question model has List of Answer, therefore it will not react. I had similar problem with nested List in mobX.

Here's a demo solution example.

The QuestionListStore has a list of QuestionStore. And we know QuestionStore has ObserverableList, it becomes reactive.

```dart
class QuestionListStore = _QuestionListStore with _$QuestionListStore;

abstract class _QuestionListStore with Store {

  @observable
  ObservableList<QuestionStore> questionList =
      ObservableList<QuestionStore>();

  @action
  void addQuestion(Question question){
       QuestionStore questionStore = QuestionStore(
        id: question.id,
        title: question.title, );
       questionList.add(questionStore);
       
       // you can access QuestionStore methods here
       questionStore.addAnswer(// instance of Answer model);
  }

}
```

```dart
class QuestionStore = _QuestionStore with _$QuestionStore;

abstract class _QuestionStore extends Question with Store {

  _QuestionStore ({
    id,
    title,
  }) : super(id: id, title: title)

  @observable
  ObservableList<Answer> answerList = ObservableList<Answer>();
  
  @action
  void addAnswer(Answer answer){
    answerList.add(answer);
  }

}
```